# summing 2 columns data in single table with different condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables `jornal_main` and `journal_item` , my `journal_main` table has got

`id | po_no  | period | post_date  | vendor 
 1  | PO123  | 12     | 2018-02-12 | XYZ
 2  | PO234  | 12     | 2018-02-13 | ABC`

journal_item is

`id | ref_id | type | sku   | qty | desc
1  | 1      | poo  | A123  | 12  | Order
2  | 1      | poo  | B234  | 20  | Order
3  | 2      | por  | A123  | 2   | Receive
4  | 2      | por  | A123  | 3   | Receive
5  | 2      | por  | B234  | 6   | Receive`

Desired output is

`po_no  | date       | vendor | item  | ordered_qty  | received_qty | balance 
po123  | 2018-02-12 | XYZ    | A123  | 12           | 5            | 7
po123  | 2018-02-12 | ABC    | B234  | 20           | 6            | 14`

i am not getting how to combine 2 queries in a single query. Here i have 2 queries which gives me `ordered_qty` and `received_qty`

**for ordered_qty**

`select journal_main.id, journal_main.po_no, journal_main.post_date, journal_main.vendor,  journal_item. sku,  SUM(journal_item.qty)  AS Oqty FROM journal_main INNER JOIN journal_item ON journal_main.id=journal_item.ref_id WHERE journal_item.type='poo' GROUP BY journal_item.sku, journal_main.id`

**for received_qty**

`select journal_main.id, journal_main.po_no, journal_main.post_date, journal_main.vendor,  journal_item. sku,  SUM(journal_item.qty)  AS Rqty FROM journal_main INNER JOIN journal_item ON journal_main.id=journal_item.ref_id WHERE journal_item.type='por' GROUP BY journal_item.sku, journal_main.id`

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select ji.ref_id,
       sum(case when ji.desc = 'Order' then qty else 0 end) as ordered,
       sum(case when ji.desc = 'Receive' then qty else 0 end) as received,
       sum(case when ji.desc = 'Order' then qty else - qty end) as total
from journal_item ji
where ji.desc in ('Order', 'Receive')
group by ji.ref_id;
```

This just provides the aggregation columns.  You should be able to join in the rest of the columns that you want.

Comment: I did like this : 
`select jm.po_no, jm.vendor, jm.post_date, ji.ref_id, sum(case when ji.type = 'poo' then qty else 0 end) as ordered, sum(case when ji.type = 'por' then qty else 0 end) as received, sum(case when ji.type = 'poo' then qty else - qty end) as total from journal_main jm INNER JOIN journal_item ji ON jm.id=ji.ref_id where ji.type in ('poo', 'por') group by jm.id` 
but it returns ordered and received in separate row

Comment: @user3368088 . . . Does this answer return one row per `ref_id`?  It should.

Comment: actually for ordered it returns 1 row and for received it comes in next row wherein it has to display in a same row